# Нельзя выбрать базу данных

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Вообщем на практике работаю в c# windows формах (в vs 2019). Хотел подключить базу данных. Сначала отсутствовал компонент DataGridView, но можно было подключить базу данных. Обновил vs до более новой версии (16.8.2), DataGridView появился, но теперь нельзя в нем выбрать базу данных (скриншот). Снизу должна быть кнопка
[image: нельзя добавить бд]

Вот так вот у меня. А должно быть вот так вот: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вообщем помогите пожалуйста :( Или подскажите, в чем может быть причина (т.к. у моего друга все нормально)

Comment: Визуальный компонент DataSet ещё не сделан для .NET 5. Либо ждите (сколько - неизвестно), либо переходите на старый .NET FW, либо создавайте источник данных (DataSet) вручную в коде. Также я видел следующий совет: создайте DataSource в проекте на Framework, а затем скопируйте готовый код в проект на .NET Core / .NET 5. PS: ваш друг использует проект другого типа. У него Framework 4.*, у вас - .NET Core или .NET 5.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо большое, хоть понял в чем проблема. А не знаете ли вы, можно ли как-то даунгрейднуть версию vs тогда? (например на 16.7.2)

Comment: Версия vs не имеет значения, значение имеет только целевой фреймворк проекта. Пропишите `DataSource` в коде, и дело с концом.

Comment: @aepot, чтобы я знал как это сделать(

Comment: Посмотрите в код дизайнера второго проекта, заберите код оттуда. Либо создайте .NET Framework 4.7.2 проект, добавьте в него таблицу и DS, откройте код дизайнера `Form1.Designer.cs` и заберите себе код подключения к базе.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо :)